# Small Camera View in App

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

Just to clarify, I am very new to coding. This project that I am doing right now as one attribute that is way beyond anything I've learned as of yet, but I really would like to figure this out so I can build the rest of my simple app.

In my app I would like to have a live camera feed from the back camera of the iPhone. I don't want this view to take up the entire screen, I want to have it just as a small portion. I don't even want this camera to take pictures I would rather it just have the live feed and that's it. I am using swift and Xcode 7.

Any chance someone can point me to a tutorial or give some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p707takeAPicAVFoundation/ch30p966takeAPicAVFoundation/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use AV Foundation. You want an AVCaptureSession (to run the camera) and an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (to display what the camera sees).

Comment: Thanks for your time.